# How can one use a rename batch file and maintain original file's extension but also has periods in the new file name?

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a group of several documents where I am needing to rename files to new filenames with multiple periods in them. There are various types of file extensions.

Example:

*REN "ABC123.*"* *"new.filename.here.*"*
This won't function, as the multiple periods in the new filename confuses the system and it doesn't understand where the file extension should actually be. This ends up renaming it to **new.filename.here** in error.

The output in the above example (if ABC123 was a PDF file) should end up as **new.filename.here.PDF**. If ABC123 was an XLSX file, then it should end up as **new.filename.here.XLSX**

Any ideas as to accomplishing this?

Comment: Rename they one by one in a `for /F` command: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /A:-D /B ABC123.*') do ren "%%a" "new.filename.here%%~Xa"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this action directly from the prompt, try

```
for %e in (abc123*) do echo ren "%e" "new.filename.here%~xe"
```

But for convenience, create a file named something like `chgname.bat` (absolutely **not** `ren.bat` or `rename.bat`) with the following content:

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%e in ("%~1*") do echo ren "%%e" "%~2%%~xe"
GOTO :EOF
```

If you locate this filename in any directory located on the `path` (see `PATH` from the prompt - it's a semicolon-separated list of directories examined by windows when locating an executable that is not found in the current directory) then

```
chgname abc123 new.filename.here
```

will change those names for you.

Noting : **BOTH OF THESE METHODS** will simply `echo` the `ren` command for verification. Change `echo ren` to `ren` to activate the rename.

I've included no safety measures in the batch file such that it may resist invalid input.

With the batch version, executing `chgname "abc123" "new.file with a space name.here"` could be used to change `abc123*` to `new.file with a space name.here*` - the quotes allow for spaces in names.